# Create a chart in Power apps that dynamically updates when item added to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp

I have a list that has a choice field that shows 'pending', 'active' and 'closed'. Is there a way to show the count of an item based on those attributes in a Power Apps pie chart? Do I need to create two lists and use a lookup column?

Comment: Give some more information about your list schema. What to show in x&y axis... or d you want to show the count of Pending, active, closed in chart??

Comment: @little_big_thoughts normally i want  to use a pie chart that show three section,that is active,close,pending and there count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below formula in `PieChart->Items`

```
Table(
    {Col: "Open", Value: CountRows(Filter(Issues, Issue_x0020_Status.Value = "Open"))
    },
    {Col: "Rejected", Value: CountRows(Filter(Issues, Issue_x0020_Status.Value = "Rejected"))
    },
    {Col: "Closed", Value: CountRows(Filter(Issues, Issue_x0020_Status.Value = "Closed"))
    },
    {Col: "In-Progress", Value: CountRows(Filter(Issues, Issue_x0020_Status.Value = "In-Progress"))
    }
)
```

[image]

> Sample formula applies for **column chart & line chart**.